# How to perform mathematical operation on regression output layer

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a simple regression neural network like this:

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R

def nn_model(2):
  in = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[80, 80, 3])

  x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(in)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)

  out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")(x)

  ####### Perform math operation here
  r = R.from_euler('z', out.numpy(), degrees=True)
  rMat = r.as_matrix()
  #######

  return tf.keras.Model(inputs=in, outputs=rMat)
```

I want to perform a mathematical operation on the output regression layer 'out' inside the network. Is it possible to access its value from inside the NN? Running the code above gives this error:

```
  AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Comment: You can get layers output by their output attribute. for example ``out.output.numpy()``. But using this to computation like what you intended, is not possible. You can get layers output after model training. For your purpose you should use a Lambda layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keras layers do not output tensor values, they instead output a tensor specification (KerasTensor) used to get the shape, dtypes and other attribute of the previous layer.
So no, it's not possible to access the value of a layer, as it has no value.

What you can do instead is to use a LambdaLayer which let you apply any pythonic code to the "real" output of the layer.

```
r = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: R.from_euler('z', x))(out)
```

Note that I'm not sure this will work, as the function inside the lambda should preferably use tensorflow operations, and should be differentiable.